# Does Wildcard SSL for a .dev possible?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain

**This is for a .dev domain name**

I know how to install a wildcard certificate on a domain name with Let's encrypt

I install Certbot and run this command

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --manual-public-ip-logging-ok -d '*.example.dev' -d example.dev
```

The SSL certificate is intalled correctly I can see *.example.dev in the certificate but the connection is not "Secure" and all .dev domain name needs to have a valide SSL certificate to access the website.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn’t matter what kind of TLD it is. You didn’t configure your web server properly for sure. There’s no such thing as “SSL from google”

Comment: it's not a SSL from Google, it's a .dev

Comment: the same steps are working for a .com TLD but not for the .dev same apache config only the TLD is changing

Answer (score 1):

The registry (Google) for `.DEV` just mandates you to have a certificate, as normally explained by your registrar during checkout/transfer of your domain name.

Why?

Because Google added `.DEV` (and some others of its TLDs) to the HSTS preloading list, which means that browsers will never attempt HTTP queries to `.dev` websites, only HTTPS one.

But besides that it changes nothing on what happens during the TLS handshake in the HTTPS exchange, so that certificates are validated exactly as any other cases/TLDs.

So, you can use a wildcard.

Besides that you are not giving actual data, such as the name, so it is difficult to help you (you should then try things yourself with `wget` and `curl` and also look at your console/debug window inside the browser), and your question is kind of offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are publicly trusted certificates in use which have wildcards for `*.whatever-domain.dev`. For example `www.google.dev` has a certificate with `*.google.dev` and other wildcards inside. Thus, it is more likely a wrong configuration on your side.